# ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion not alert ，granted always no

Tags: ios, objective-c, alert

```
ABAuthorizationStatus status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus();
if (status == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    NSLog(@"未知");
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL,NULL);

        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            if (granted) {
                NSLog(@"ok");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"nonono,always here");
            }


            CFRelease(addressBook);
        });
  }
```

If I create a new project, this code will compile.

But in my current project no alert is given and the build fails with the following error 
 **kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined state and granted = nil**

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what the variable "status" is from your code. You can try with following code.

```
if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil);
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            if (granted) {
                //You've got contacts permission
            } else {
                //User denied to give permission
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: simulator 8,it will show alert ;but simulator 9, not alert;

Comment: on simulator 9,not alert and always log "nonono,always here";

Comment: You need to use CNContactStore to get contacts on iOS 9. This link can help you https://gist.github.com/willthink/024f1394474e70904728